# increasing ps -o column width

Tags: ps, text-formatting

When I run the command

```
ps -e -o cmd,stime,etime=
```

the `cmd` comlumn is truncated, so that the `cmd` path is trunctated.
How do I format the column width so that all the text is displayed?

Comment: On which unix variant?

Comment: The Centos variant

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404912/6860) for a script that neatly automates setting the width of the UID column in `ps` output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In GNU/Linux you can set the column width as follows:

```
ps -e -o cmd:50,stime,etime=
```

From the [ps(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) manual page:

> -o format
>
> User-defined format. format is a single argument in the form of a
>     blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way to specify
>     individual output columns. The recognized keywords are described in
>     the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below. Headers may be renamed
>     (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired. If all column
>     headers are empty (ps -o pid= -o comm=) then the header line will not
>     be output. Column width will increase as needed for wide headers; this
>     may be used to widen up columns such as WCHAN (ps -o
>     pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm). **Explicit width control (ps
>     opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.** The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y
>     varies with personality; output may be one column named "X,comm=Y" or
>     two columns named "X" and "Y". Use multiple -o options when in doubt.
>     Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable to specify a default as
>     desired; DefSysV and DefBSD are macros that may be used to choose the
>     default UNIX or BSD columns.

Comment: Is there an option to fit the max row with?

Comment: No, AFAIK you can only set a fixed width. I added the `ps(1)` explanation about this.

Comment: In case you can swap the columns, you may put the command at the end. With `ps -e -o stime,etime=,cmd` the full command line is printed.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04, the command:

```
ps -eo comm:25,pid
```

does indeed widen the COMMAND column, but it doesn't stop truncation, even in commands shorter than 25 characters:

```
gsd-printer                2384 
gvfsd-trash                2397
evolution-calen            2401
ibus-engine-sim            2429
dconf-service              2436
evolution-calen            2445
evolution-addre            2457
evolution-addre            2468
fwupd                      2488
```